# Interpreting coefficients in Linear regression with categorical variables and one hot encoding (drop first)

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, regularization, categorical-encoding, stepwise-regression

I am doing multiple linear regression where my independent variables are a mix of categorical and numerical variables. Obviously I need to one-hot-encode the categorical variables, and I need to "drop-first" to prevent collinearity (since I want to interpret my coefficients).

Assume a one-hot-encoded categorical variable $X$ with $n$ categories. When I drop the first variable $X_1$, obviously my coefficients will correspond to $X_{2..n}.$ i.e. I will have a linear model
$$y = c_0 + c_1X_2 + c_2X_3 + ...$$
What does this mean? How do I get information about how $X_1$ affects the model? Can I extract it from the other coefficients or do I need to construct another model and drop another value e.g. $X_2$? Is it the case that the coefficients change meaning i.e. $c_1$ describes how $X_2$ affects the model in relation to $X_1$? If so, what is the best way to get the coefficients for all parameters $X_{1..n}$ so that $c_i$ describes how $X_i$ affects the model? Can I use regularization?

Comment: The question isn`t very clear, but you seem to use drop-one to drop one (or more) of the dummys that as a group represent a categorical variable. That should never be done, see for instance https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182121/stepwise-regression-and-variable-selection-with-categorical-variables-in-r